# How can I visualize single image with only one convolutional layer and one pooling layers?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I wrote this sample code to show only a single image after passing it to my model. The model should have only one convolutional layer and one pooling layer. Or in another way, how can I visualize a single image by passing it to a simple neural network that has one convolutional and one pooling layer?

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn #creating neural network
from PIL import Image
from numpy import asarray

# Set up GPU
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

# load the image
image = Image.open('./img.png')

# convert image to numpy array
data = asarray(image)
print(type(data))
print(data.shape)
```

now building the arch.

```
class ConvNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        #convolutional layer
        self.layer = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=3, kernel_size=2, stride=1, padding=0),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2))
        
    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.layer(x)
        return out


convnet = ConvNet().to(device) #set up for GPU if available
convnet
```

pass image to my model
`outputs = convnet(data) imshow(outputs)`

got the error below

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_3184/1768392595.py in <module>
----> 1 outputs = convnet(data)
      2 imshow(outputs)


TypeError: conv2d() received an invalid combination of arguments - got (numpy.ndarray, Parameter, Parameter, tuple, tuple, tuple, int), but expected one of:
 * (Tensor input, Tensor weight, Tensor bias, tuple of ints stride, tuple of ints padding, tuple of ints dilation, int groups)
      didn't match because some of the arguments have invalid types: (numpy.ndarray, Parameter, Parameter, tuple, tuple, tuple, int)
 * (Tensor input, Tensor weight, Tensor bias, tuple of ints stride, str padding, tuple of ints dilation, int groups)
      didn't match because some of the arguments have invalid types: (numpy.ndarray, Parameter, Parameter, tuple, tuple, tuple, int)
```

I expect to show image after passed during this sample network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as GoodDeeds mentioned, CNN expects the data to be of type `Tensor` you have read the image using PIL and then converted it to NumPy array, you will need to convert the NumPy array to Tensor using  `torch.from_numpy(data)`

Below code will solve the issue

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn #creating neural network
from PIL import Image
from numpy import asarray

#Set up GPU
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
Her I am loading my image 
# load the image
image = Image.open('./img.png')
# convert image to numpy array
data = asarray(image)
data=torch.from_numpy(data)
print(type(data))
print(data.shape)`
```

Answer (score 1):

The input to the CNN needs to be of the `torch.Tensor` type. You can do this by applying the transform directly on the PIL image, as:

```
data = torchvision.transforms.functional.to_tensor(image)
```

or

```
transform = torchvision.transforms.ToTensor() # can be composed with other transforms if necessary
data = transform(image)
```